# Enable: Asp.net connection pool monitoring with performance monitor

Tags: performance, monitoring, connection, pool

I'm a C# developer, but I'm running in a system management issue here.

**Intro**:

I'm suspecting that an ASP.NET application is having some issues with the connection pool and that the pool is flooding from time to time. So to make sure, I want to monitor the connection pool. After some searching I found this article: [Ensure Proper SQL Server Connection Pooling](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/blog/b/community_blog/posts/ensure-proper-sql-server-connection-pooling).

Basically it explains stuff about connection pools and how you can monitor the application pool with performance monitor.

**The problem**:

So I logged in to the ASP.NET server(The SQL database is hosted on a different server) which hosts the web site. I started performance monitor, but when I want to select 'Current # pooled and nonpooled connections', I have no instance to select. Therefore I can't add it.

**Question**

How can I create/supply an instance so I can monitor the connection pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this is just a bug. To work around it, just select the counter group:  '.net data provider for sql server', which supplies the same counters and do work. (Or oracle if you  use an orcle database server).